# How to set checkbox in a table checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I have a table I have the `id` of the checkbox that I want to set as checked, but I cannot do it and I don't know why.

I try with this, but nothing happens and I don't have any kind of error message:

```js
$('#medicalListTable input.type_checkbox[id="sindicate-345"]').prop('checked', true);
$('input.type_checkbox[id="sindicate-345"]').prop('checked', true);
$('input.type_checkbox[id="sindicate-345"]').attr('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="medicalListTable" class="display responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="medicalListTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Id empleado: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 134px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Id empleado<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Nombre: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 174px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Nombre<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Apellidos: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 329px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Apellidos<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Seleccionar: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 125px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Seleccionar<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="vehicleId sorting_1">345</td>
      <td class="model">NAME</td>
      <td class="model">SURNAME</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sindicate-345">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `type_checkbox` class on the element. I presume you meant to use an attribute selector like this instead:

```
$('#medicalListTable input[type="checkbox"][id="sindicate-345"]').prop('checked', true);
```

**However**, if you have an `id` on the element it should be unique in the DOM so that is the only selector you need to use:

```
$('#sindicate-345').prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$('#sindicate-345').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="medicalListTable" class="display responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="medicalListTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Id empleado: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 134px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Id empleado<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Nombre: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 174px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Nombre<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Apellidos: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 329px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Apellidos<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Seleccionar: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 125px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Seleccionar<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="vehicleId sorting_1">345</td>
      <td class="model">NAME</td>
      <td class="model">SURNAME</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sindicate-345">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wow, so simply and it works, thanks a lot! I think that it could be a different way to code if the checkbox is in a table, but it doesn't! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

As the attribute [***id***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) is unique in a document you can simply use that:

```js
$('#sindicate-345').attr('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="medicalListTable" class="display responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="medicalListTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting ui-state-default sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Id empleado: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 134px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Id empleado<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Nombre: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 174px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Nombre<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Apellidos: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 329px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Apellidos<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Seleccionar: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 125px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Seleccionar<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="vehicleId sorting_1">345</td>
        <td class="model">NAME</td>
        <td class="model">SURNAME</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sindicate-345">
        </td>
    </tr>        
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by

```
$('#sindicate-345').attr('Checked','Checked');
```

```js
$('#sindicate-345').attr('Checked','Checked');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="medicalListTable" class="display responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="medicalListTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr role="row">
          <th class="sorting ui-state-default sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Id empleado: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 134px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Id empleado<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Nombre: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 174px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Nombre<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Apellidos: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 329px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Apellidos<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Seleccionar: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 125px;">
            <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Seleccionar<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
          <td class="vehicleId sorting_1">345</td>
          <td class="model">NAME</td>
          <td class="model">SURNAME</td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sindicate-345">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

or

```
$("#sindicate-345").prop("checked", true);
```

```js
$("#sindicate-345").prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="medicalListTable" class="display responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="medicalListTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Id empleado: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 134px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Id empleado<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Nombre: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 174px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Nombre<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Apellidos: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 329px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Apellidos<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
      <th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="medicalListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Seleccionar: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 125px;">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Seleccionar<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="vehicleId sorting_1">345</td>
      <td class="model">NAME</td>
      <td class="model">SURNAME</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sindicate-345">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this works too, as the other answers, I choose the first one because is the first I see and I finally used. Thanks!